# GLSL : Vertices are missing

Tags: opengl, glsl

When I use immediate mode, it draws correctly but when i pass the same vertices to the GPU, or even point them, it doesn't work.

there is a position buffer holding vertices :

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> posbuf;
```

and indices for it.

immediate mode :

```
for (unsigned int i =0; i < indices.size(); i++) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(posbuf[indices[i].index[0]].x, posbuf[indices[i].index[0]].y, posbuf[indices[i].index[0]].z);
    glVertex3f(posbuf[indices[i].index[1]].x, posbuf[indices[i].index[1]].y, posbuf[indices[i].index[1]].z);
    glVertex3f(posbuf[indices[i].index[2]].x, posbuf[indices[i].index[2]].y, posbuf[indices[i].index[2]].z);
    glEnd();
    }
```

and this is the vertex attribute code :

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GL_ATTRIB_POS);
glVertexAttribPointer(GL_ATTRIB_POS, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,&posbuf[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indVBO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GL_ATTRIB_POS);
```

and a shader for it :

```
#version 120
attribute vec3 position;
void main()
{
    vec4 finalv=vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(finalv.xyz,1.0);
}

[frag]
#version 120


void main()
{
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

immediate result : [image]

shader result: 
[image]

I don't know what's wrong, i also tried to pass posbuf using glm::value_ptr, they all give the same result. I am on fedora 18, supporting glsl up to #version 140, opengl 3.3.

EDIT :

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Triangle) * indices.size(), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

struct Triangle {
int index[3];
};
```

Comment: Show the `BufferData` call for indices VBO. Also, out of curiosity, why aren't you using a VBO for positions too?

Comment: I am already using VBO, but when it didn't work, i wanted to try it more specifically by just extracting position buffer, manually pointing it. But it still gives the same result as VBO.

Comment: then most certainly it's the index vbo that's causing the problem

Comment: I added index uploading.

Comment: no what's `Triangle` and `sizeof(Triangle)`? -.-

Comment: Where is `GL_ATTRIB_POS` defined?

Comment: #define GL_ATTRIB_POS 0
glBindAttribLocation(shader->shaderProgram, GL_ATTRIB_POS, "position");

Comment: If the indices buffer holds `Triangle`s, its `.size()` is only 1/3 of all indices obviously.

Comment: Ohhhh god, thank you so much !! It works now. It is a shame to forget it everytime lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your `indices` vector contains complete triangles consisting of 3 indices each. But then in `glDrawElements` you use `indices.size()` as the number of elements to draw. But `glDrawElements` doesn't take the number of primitives, but the number of *indices*, so you're missing 2/3 of your triangles. It should rather be

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size() * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

(And `indices` should be renamed to `triangles` to avoid further confusion. By the way, `index` should probably be `unsigned int[3]` as promised to OpenGL. On any reasonable system there won't be a representational difference between `int`s and `unsigned int`s, but it is a bit inconsistent to use `int` while telling OpenGL it's an `unsigned int`.)

Comment: Here, have a +1 for the stolen answer :)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Well, don't bother with comments if you already spotted the problem. (I might even have refrained from writing an answer had I read your comment beforehand) ;)

Comment: I have just read the last comment that confirmed the fix, and pretty much at the same point your answer appeared. No worries, I'll be faster next time `:>`.